# Can someone explain why int takes on different sizes depending on system architecture?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, architecture

Word on the street is that an `int` varies size depending on the system architecture (which I assume refers specifically to the processor architecture, though I'm probably wrong). That seems like that would be a really brittle setup when trying to run old software on newer processors, or as processors change in general. What was the motivation behind pegging the size of an integer to system architecture?

Also a (related) follow-up question. How does a system with say an IA-32 architecture reach a memory address that's greater than 4G?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Different CPUs have different design constraints. For example, transistors were more costly in the 80s because of this some chips only implemented a 16bit cpu word. For efficiency an int would be made to match that. Newer CPUs have a much higher transistor count at a lower cost so 'wasting' a few on passing around all those high order 0's when adding small numbers has a lower cost. In newer CPUs there is less of a problem with 32bit or potentially even 64bit integers.

Add into the mix special purpose CPUs and it can get really complex. I have heard of 24bit and 48bit CPUs for sound and video processing. I have not seen them myself but it is not hard to write code to be word size agnostic and the chips could theoretically exist.

For more details see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_(computer_architecture)

Physical Address Extension(PAE) is a CPU extension that allows the developer to access more memory via CPU instructions. It kept a table of memory addresses that referenced the higher regions of memory. It incurred the cost of a double pointer dereference in practice, that is usually preferable to using swap space or other disk buffer when you consider the speed of RAM and L2 cache.
Wikipedia has a decent page on it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_Address_Extension